# Spring data rest returning 200 with response body on postman but the same api call via groovy client gives 204 status with no response body

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

Spring data rest returning 200 with response body on postman but the same api call via groovy client gives 204 status with no response body.

Can somebody suggest what might be going on or how to proceed with the debugging. I am fairly new to web development.

Comment: Can you show configuration being use for Postman and Groovy client? Make sure you are using correct request method (GET, POST, etc) in both places.

Comment: Hi @HarshilSharma. I figured a way to get around this issue. In spring data rest we can explicitly set returnBodyOnCreate and returnBodyOnUpdate.